# Reading output from the command line

Tags: console-application, wget, outputstream

I'm trying to write a simple GUI for Wget. I'm looking for advice on how to read information from the command line output that Wget generates when it is doing a run. I'd like to update that download information real time to a list box or some equivalent. The GUI will be in Visual Basic. I know programs like WinWget do this, and their source code is available, but I don't know the language that's written in well enough to find what I'm looking for.

**tl;dr:** I need to update a list box real time with command line output.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to use the output of one console application for the input of an other:

The first way is to use the `|` operator; for example:

```
dir |more
```

The second way is to write the data into a file and process it later.

```
dir > data.txt
```

Comment: Can you explain more about the | method? What exactly goes into the "more" of "|more".
My last-resort solution is your second one, to write the output to a text file then update it using that. However, that wouldn't really be "real time." At best, there would be a significant delay each time I updated the screen- opening the file, copying the data, closing the file, copying it to the list box, etc.